# VS2010 storage place of batch information

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I use "Batch Build" in Visual Studio 2010 and select specific build and platform options there - in which file is this information stored?

I'm asking this because I have to add this file to version control system in order to not to configure the same again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, these information are stored in .suo file.